# IntelliJIDEA: How to see unpushed commits?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Scenario: I'm using several different repositories.  I make local commits to all of them using the version control window in IntelliJ. After I commit, it gives me the option to push all of the commits to the remote origin as well.  I decline this since I'm not ready to push, but sometime later I would like to push all of my local commits.

I don't see any easy way to do this in IntelliJ.  The "local changes" tab is empty, and the commits in the "log" tab have no option to push them with right-click menu.  Is there a way?

Comment: Asking just to be sure: you want to push from *multiple repositories* at once?

Comment: Correct.  It's possible with the popup that automatically follows committing to multiple repositories at once, but I don't see anyway to reclaim that type of window after dismissing it.